# How can I get the concrete type of a generic type variable using mirrors in Dart?

Tags: generics, dart, dart-mirrors

Assuming I have a `List` of `String`s like this.

```dart
var myList = new List<String>();
```

How can I figure out that `myList` is a `List` of `String`s using mirrors?

---

I tried it using the `typeVariables` of `ClassMirror` but the mirror seems to just describe the gerneric `List` class.

```dart
InstanceMirror im = reflect(myList); // InstanceMirror on instance of 'List'
ClassMirror cm = im.type; // ClassMirror on 'List'
print(cm.typeVariables['E']) // TypeVariableMirror on 'E'
```

I also found this in the documentation but I have yet to find a `ClassMirror` instance where accessing `originalDeclaration` doesn't throw a `NoSuchMethodError`.

> **final ClassMirror originalDeclaration**
>
> A mirror on the original declaration of this type.
>
> For most classes, they are their own original declaration. For generic
>   classes, however, there is a distinction between the original class
>   declaration, which has unbound type variables, and the instantiations
>   of generic classes, which have bound type variables.

Comment: FWIW I opened this bug to track: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7957  You might want to star it to get notifications when something changes.

Comment: Note, your example should be more accurate and use this as the example: `var myList = new List<String>()`  because in Dart, types are optional, so you want to show the actual object instantiation.

Comment: @SethLadd Thanks for your answer. I changed my example accordingly. So I guess the answer would be "Not possible until that bug is fixed"? Shouldn't then this be the (accepted) answer here?

Comment: I'm not entirely positive it's a bug. Once we see the bug triaged and responded to, we'll know our answer :)

Answer (score 8):

2 possible methods.

The first method is to check the variable's type using `is` operator, as it's more performant than reflection:

```
var myList = new List<String>();
print(myList is List<int>); // false
print(myList is List<String>); // true
```

The second method is to use [ClassMirror.typeArguments](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_mirrors/ClassMirror.html#typeArguments):

```
import 'dart:mirrors';
var myList = new List<String>();

Map typeArguments = reflect(myList).type.typeArguments;
print(typeArguments); // {Symbol("T"): ClassMirror on 'String'}

ClassMirror firstTypeArg = typeArguments[typeArguments.keys.first];
print(firstTypeArg.reflectedType); // String
```