# Find generic type of Iterable (Set<E>, List<E>, ...) via introspection

Tags: generics, dart, dart-mirrors

I tried without any success to find the generic type of an `Iterable` class (such as `Set<myGenericType>` or `List<myOtherGenericType>`).

For instance :

if `instanceMirror.getField(myField).reflectee` is a `Set<Toto>` then I have no solution to retrieve the type `Toto` via introspection.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384865

Comment: You're right... but your response is more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class A<T> {
  T item;
  List<T> items;
}

main() {
  var m = reflectType(new A<int>().runtimeType);

  var itemType = m.declarations[#item].type as TypeMirror;
  print('type of #item: ${itemType.qualifiedName}');  // type of #item: ClassMirror on 'int'.

  var itemsType = m.declarations[#items].type as ClassMirror;
  print('type of #items: ${itemsType.qualifiedName}');  // type of #items: ClassMirror on 'List'.

  print('type arguments of #items: ${itemsType.typeArguments.map((t) => t.qualifiedName)}');  // type arguments of #items: [TypeVariableMirror on 'T'].
}
```